# Dependency error with excel interop dll in .NET app

Tags: .net, excel-interop

I am running a .NET app on my local machine that uses the microsoft excel interop library. It has been working until today when I removed the library and then added it back into the project. Until a few weeks ago I had been using a trial version of Excel for this application to work and it was even working after my trial had expired. But I am afraid that now since the trial expired AND I removed the library from my project and put it back in that this is what is causing this error. Am I correct here? Should re-installing excel fix this problem?

Here is the error I get when I try to run the application:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

and the logs:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Aaron-PC\Aaron
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite1/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Aaron/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fd4ebee9/714ba73d/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Aaron/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fd4ebee9/714ba73d/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite1/bin/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Also I am aware of the fact that Microsoft doesn't recommend using excel in .NET apps so please do not factor that into your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Delete that reference, clean your solution, close Visual Studio and open the solution again, add the reference and build solution.

Comment: how do you clean the solution? I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: right-click on solution and select "clean solution". Or go to menu "build-clean solution". Or, since you on VS2012, in the right top search box type - "clean..." and you will see. I also really think that all you need to do is to re-add the reference

Comment: I couldn't find any of those options, could it be because I'm using Visual studio Express?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828797/dont-see-clean-solution-option-in-visual-studio You can also clean using `devenv /clean SolnConfigName SolutionName` in the command line environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` dll from my project and changing the assembly in my web.config file to match the assembly found in `C:\Windows\assembly` and now it works. I was tipped off by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net/15411971#15411971).