# Not shwoing build and clean project in Android studio

Tags: react-native

i'm wanna run clean project and rebuild, its not showing other items in the build menu.
i have restarted the android studio but the problem is still there.
the problem is happen after installing linear gradient package and removing it.

[image: Build in android-studio]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't see Clean solution option in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828797/dont-see-clean-solution-option-in-visual-studio)

Comment: this is not the solution for my probelm

Answer (score 0):

the problem is for visual studio but mine is android studio,
now what i have to do?